# Сравнение двух чисел, больше-меньше, в Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Не пойму почему не пашут логические операторы, прочитал статейку, вроде делаю все правильно, но она сравнивает как-то по своему, вот код:

```
NSString *State0 = @"0";
    NSString *State2 = @"25";
    NSString *State3 = @"50";
    NSString *State4 = @"80";

  if (LabelSchet.text > State0)
    {
        LabelState.text = @"Ваш статус: '1'";
    }
    if (LabelSchet.text > State2)
    {
        LabelState.text = @"Ваш статус: '2'";
    }
    if (LabelSchet.text > State3)
    {
        LabelState.text = @"Ваш статус: '3'";
    }
    if (LabelSchet.text > State4)
    {
        LabelState.text = @"Ваш статус: '4'";
    }
```

В LabelState находится число - 15. Сравнивает в любом случае что в LabelState больше чем в любом NSString, что я сделал не так?

Comment: Какие типы Вы между собой сравниваете? Из текста вопроса идет что int  co string или string со  string. Это так?

Comment: String со string, про int вообще не сказано )

Comment: То есть Вы хотите сравнить значения двух чисел которые записаны в объектных строках?

Comment: Да, судя по всему именно этого))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так напрямую сравнивать низззя. Можно сделать следующим образом:

```
    NSString *string1 = @"15";
    NSString *string2 = @"25";

    NSComparisonResult result = [string1 compare:string2];

    if (result == NSOrderedAscending) { // string1 < string2

    } else if (result == NSOrderedDescending) { // string1 > string2

    }else if (result == NSOrderedSame) {// string1 == string2

    }
```

или:

```
if (result < 0) {// string1 < string2

} else if (result > 0) { // string1 > string2

} else if (result == 0) {// string1 == string2

}
```

а в Вашем случае вообще было бы правильно привести все к числам и сравнивать уже их:

```
int labelInt = [LabelSchet.text intValue];
```

или

```
NSInteger labelInteger = [LabelSchet.text  integerValue];
```

Comment: Я думаю, что приведение к числам - самый здоровый вариант для ТС, покажите ему, как это делается))

Comment: плюсую к  *привести все к числам и сравнивать уже их*. Если нужно работать только с числами то имеет смысл вообще не использовать NSString

Comment: ответ дополнил. Я думаю этой информации будет достаточно, чтобы двигаться дальше :)

Comment: Спасибо большое, это мне и нужно было.)